# Insertion Sort - counting number of inversions

Tags: java, arrays, insertion-sort

I am trying to count the number of inversions given a data set. It has worked well for small data sets but once I choose one of a couple thousand the invert value comes out negative. I can't see how this is possible, does anyone know why this is happening / potential fixes?

For example, given a data set of 5 (-6, 1, 15, 8, 10) the invert value is 2. Yet for a longer data set I'm getting -2032112517 inversions.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of array: ");
        int input= userInput.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[input];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = userInput.nextInt();
        }
        insertionSort(values);

    }
    public static void insertionSort(int values[ ]) {
        int arrlen = values.length;
        int invert = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrlen; i++) {
            int currentValue = values[i];
            int compare = i - 1;
            while (compare >= 0 && values[compare] > currentValue) {
                invert++;
                values[compare + 1] = values[compare];
                compare = compare - 1;
            }
            values[compare + 1] = currentValue;

        }
        System.out.println("INVERT IS: " +invert);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The maximum int value in Java is 2147483647, most likely an overflow has occurred. Try using long instead.

If you would like more information, search for Integer overflow on Wikipedia.